# What does the "source" attribute in a "Context" element represent in a Tomcat's server.xml configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

I am working on a Java EE application running on **Tomcat 7** server.

Into my **server.xml** configuration file I found this line:

```
<Context docBase="gaez-server" path="/ROOT" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:gaez-server"/></Host>
```

What exactly means? It seems to be refered to some **Eclipse** configuration. What can I do to bring into a remote server on a Linux machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source part on the web.xml file

> org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:gaez-server

has been generated by a Eclipse Plugin named Eclipse WebServerTools (WTP).

This plugin used your local Tomcat Server to run your web application.

So basically your Eclipse configured your **server.xml** to be able to deploy your application on local environment.

---

If you don't need any custom configuration, you could deploy your application on a remote linux tomcat without adding new lines on your server.xml file. Copy your **.war** file to **${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps** directory and run your stop/start service.

Taking those steps, your Tomcat Server will be responsible for creating new context and configure it on the appropriate files. I would not recommend editing your server.xml directly as you could break things that are already working if you delete/add some element in the incorrect location.